# MongoDB: Retrieve distinct count from two different tables

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I inherited a project that contains a lot of data in a MongoDB server. I'm writing some queries for it and came across a rather annoying problem. I need to find the number of unique values we'll call `ID`.  The problem is, they can appear in two different points depending on the origin of this data.

For example, the table could look something like this:

```
{ 
  foo: {
     ID: "ABC123"
  },
  bar: {
     ID: undefined
  }
}
```

or

```
{ 
  foo: {
     ID: undefined
  },
  bar: {
     ID: "ABC123"
  }
}
```

or

```
{ 
  foo: {
     ID: "ABC123"
  },
  bar: {
     ID: "ABC123"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't re-model the data at this point. I have a fairly limited knowledge of MongoDB. I'm wondering if there a way using aggregation to join these together so I get a set of all the IDs in to a single Document so they are all unique. It's fairly trivial to group one or the other, but grouping both will give me duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$project` then `$group` and then `$addToSet`.

```
db.c.aggregate([
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        IDS : ["$foo.ID", "$bar.ID"]
    }
},
{
    $unwind : "$IDS"
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : 1,
        distinctIds : {
            $addToSet : "$IDS"
        }
    }
}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `$group` to get `ID's` in each `bar` and `foo` doc into an array and run them through `$setUnion` to get distinct across previously grouped `ID's`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "ID": {
            $addToSet: {
                "foo_id": "$foo.ID",
                "bar_id": "$bar.ID"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "ID": {
            $setUnion: ["$ID.foo_id", "$ID.bar_id"]
        },
        _id: 0
    }
})
```